# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server on visual studio 2019 windows form

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

please help me to solve this, I got this error when I want to insert data into a database
I'm using visual studio 2019 and C#
below is the code where the message told me

```
string query = "INSERT INTO 'pengguna' ('id', 'alamat', 'jadwal_in', 'jadwal_out', 'nama', 'password', 'telp', 'tingkat') VALUES (NULL, '"+alamat.Text+"', '"+masuk.Text+ "', '" + keluar.Text + "', '" + nama.Text + "', '" + password.Text + "', '" + telp.Text + "', '" + tingkat.Text + "')";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace karyawan
{
    class Koneksi
    {
        public MySqlConnection Getconn() {
            MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection();
            Conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=;database=karyawan;";
            return Conn;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: here is my database picture]

Comment: You need to use parametrized query to avoid SQL injection and such syntax errors.

Comment: You are using single quote `'` around table name and column names in the query. You should use `. Single quote is used around values.

Comment: okay sir, i will try this right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider trying a code like this, more readable and secure (in term of sql injection)

```
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
    string SQL = "INSERT INTO 'pengguna' ('id', 'alamat', 'jadwal_in', 'jadwal_out', 'nama', 'password', 'telp', 'tingkat') " +
                 "VALUES (NULL, @Alamat, @Masuk, @Keluar, @Nama, @Password, @Telp, @Tingkat)";
    command.CommandText = SQL;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Alamat", alamat.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Masuk", masuk.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Keluar", keluar.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Nama", nama.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Password", password.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Telp", telp.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Tingkat", tingkat.Text);

    command.Connection = conn;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**OR this:**

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
string SQL = "INSERT INTO `pengguna` (`id`, `alamat`, `jadwal_in`, `jadwal_out`, `nama`, `password`, `telp`, `tingkat`) " +
         "VALUES (NULL, @Alamat, @Masuk, @Keluar, @Nama, @Password, @Telp, @Tingkat)";
command.CommandText = SQL;
command.Parameters.Add("@Alamat", alamat.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Masuk", masuk.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Keluar", keluar.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Nama", nama.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", password.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Telp", telp.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Tingkat", tingkat.Text);

command.Connection = conn;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i'm sorry sir, what is the difference between the 2 code above

Comment: i got a new error, the said that "cannot convert from 'string' to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType"

Comment: oh i already fix it by using command.parameters.addwithvalue();
your code give me a clue what should i looking for, thanks sir